# Python - basic command for extracting a JSON response item

Tags: python, json

I'm only a few days into my Python experience so I'm sorry to pollute the site with a baby-steps question.
I'm trying to write an add-on for XBMC, which I believe uses Python 2.4. I've accessed a web api, which wraps the return in JSON. I've saved the url return to a WebHTML list (I think a list!). When I enter the following from the stackoverflow tutorial:

```
decoded = json.loads(WebHTML)
print 'DECODED:', decoded
```

I get the following in my log:

`NOTICE: {u'totalItems': 1, u'query': u'Ludwig van Beethoven Op 67 Symphony No 5 in Cm (Fate)', u'kind': u'volumes#volumes', u'items': [{u'scoreId': u'IMSLP01056', u'pageCount': 42, u'title': u'Symphony No.5, Op.67 - Complete Score (S.464/5)', u'kind': u'volumes#volume', u'authors': [u'Beethoven, Ludwig van'], u'year': 1807, u'selfLink': u'http://www.peachnote.com/rest/api/v0/score?id=IMSLP01056'}]}`

I want to extract the scoreId for a subsequent url call, i.e. IMSLP01056, but I'm struggling with the correct command. When I try:

```
dict = json.loads(WebHTML)
dict['items']['scoreId']
print dict['items']['scoreId']
```

The log error returned is:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

If I try:

```
print dict[4][1]
```

it returns

```
KeyError: (4,)
```

I've tried a variety of JSONloads commands but can't get any to work. I always get an error beginning:

`IOError: (2, 'No such file or directory', '{\n  "kind": "volumes#volumes",\n  "query": "Ludwig ..... etc, etc.`

So, I'm a little stumped as to the correct command I should use. Thanks and sorry if this is too much info for a very basic question.

Comment: print dict['items'][0]['scoreId']

Comment: Using `dict` as a variable name is a very bad idea as it shadows the built-in name.

Comment: Thanks larsmans, I've changed 'dict' to 'scoreId', though I still get the same error.

Comment: spicavigo - it still tells me must be integer not str.

Answer (score 2):

The main response you're getting is indeed a dictionary, but the value for its `items` key is a list. So the error is telling you to use an integer index for that inner lookup. So:

```
dict['items'][0]['scoreId']
```

Note that there are potentially many items inside that `items` list, and the above will only give you the first: you probably want all of them in a single list:

```
scores = [item['scoreId'] for item in dict['items']]
```

which will iterate through all items, and extract their scores into a separate list.

Also, as larsmans says, don't use `dict` (or `list`) as a variable name, as it hides the built-in `dict()` function.

Comment: Ooh, now it does work. Sorry, I forgot to amend the preceding line as well. Thanks everyone - told you I was a beginner!! Can't believe how quickly you helped.